# PAPS , is it a carrier or not

Tags: medicinal-chemistry

In sulfate conjugation , is it considered as a carrier or help to make sulfonation if I got a question and I have to choose ( enzyme helps to make the reaction or is a carrier to transfer the sulfate ) I know isn't an enzyme but it does help in the reaction , that what I understand

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3%27-Phosphoadenosine-5%27-phosphosulfate, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfotransferase Btw bould you improve grammar?